# EKF update with 0 uncertainty measurement noise

Tags: kalman-filter

I was trying to understand how the Kalman gain works, from what I understand it determines the reliance on the measurement based on current state and measurement uncertainty.

The Kalman gain, K, is given by

$$ K_k = P_k H^T (H P_k H^T + R)^{-1} $$

for predicted state covariance $P_k$, measurement Jacobian $H$, and measurement noise $R$. I am using values from an example discussed in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40487/kalman-filter-update-returns-an-invalid-covariance-matrix) other question.

$$ P_k = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 200.25 & 100.5 \\ 100.5 & 101 \end{array} \right) $$

$$ H = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$

so for $R = \left( 0 \right)$, I am getting 
$$K_k = \left(\begin{array}{c} 1.0000 \\ 0.5019 \end{array} \right).$$

However simplification of the Kalman gain equation for $R = \left( 0 \right)$ becomes 
$$ K_k = P_k H^T (H P_k H^T + 0)^{-1} $$
$$ K_k = P_k H^T (H P_k H^T)^{-1} $$
$$ K_k = P_k H^T (P_k H^T)^{-1} H^{-1} $$
$$K_k = H^{-1}$$
Which in my opinion is a pseudo inverse, accordingly
$$K_k = \left(\begin{array}{c} 1.0000 \\ 0.0 \end{array} \right).$$

am I violating anything fundamental, or is it just computer approximation error?

Comment: Can you clarify the claimed 'simplification of the Kalman gain equation' ?

Comment: I have modified the question to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplification of the Kalman gain attempted in the question is mistaken. $H$ and $P_k\,H^\mathrm{T}$ are not square matrices in this case (the measurement and the state have different dimensions) and thus $(H \, P_k \, H^\mathrm{T})^{-1}$ cannot be written as $(P_k\, H^\mathrm{T})^{-1}\,H^{-1}$. The latter expression does not even make sense since $H$  and $P_k\,H^\mathrm{T}$ do not have inverses.

(Pseudoinverse exists, but it does not have all properties inverse has.)